# Convert SQL query to Zend DB Select

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

How to convert this query to a Zend DB Query

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.station, t1.ftype, t1.price, t1.currency 
FROM fueling as t1  
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(t2.date) as maxdate, t2.station, t2.ftype 
FROM fueling as t2   
GROUP BY t2.station, t2.ftype) as t3
ON t1.date=t3.maxdate AND t1.station=t3.station AND t1.ftype=t3.ftype
where t1.station in ('GF112','GF11')
ORDER by t1.station,t1.ftype;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below one

```
$subselect = $this->db->select()
        ->from(array('t2'       => 'fueling'),
               array(
                    'maxdate' => 'MAX(t2.date)',
                    'station' => 't2.station',
                    'ftype' => 't2.ftype',
            ));

$select = $this->db->select()
            ->from(array('t1'       => 'fueling'),
                   array(
                        'date' => 't1.date',
                        'station' => 't1.station',
                        'ftype' => 't1.ftype',
                        'price'=>'t1.price',
                        'currency'=>'t1.currency'
                ))
            ->JOIN(array('t3'=>$subselect),'t1.date=t3.maxdate and t1.station=t3.station and t1.ftype=t3.ftype')
            ->Where('t1.station IN (?)', array('GF112','GF11')');

$results = $this->db->query($select)->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I was a little changed your subquery and now all is well. thank you so much